# Add Some Links to some words issue

Tags: php

I have some words Such as

"Hello this article about games. Our choice is train games. Name of game is My Little Train"

I want to add automatic links as below

**"games" » "http://www.mywebsite.com"**

**"train games" » "http://www.myothersiteadrwesss.com"**

**"game" » "http://www.my3thsiteadress.com"**

I tried it with PHP and `str_replace` but after my codes

"games" word has 2 links nested  ("http://www.mywebsite.com" and "http://www.my3thsiteadress.com" )

"train games" word has 3 links nested (all 3 links)

How can I solve my problem?

finally i want

```
<a href="http://www.my3thsiteadress.com">game</a>
<a href="http://www.myothersiteadrwesss.com">train games</a>
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com">games</a>
```

words count can be change

Comment: Start by replacing `train games` then replace `games` and lastly `game`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace`. That way, you can specify a much stricter regexp to be replaced (Somewhat like a "match whole word"). Here, take a look at  http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 1):

#### Best way is to multi replace, step by step...

```
<?php
    $string = "Hello this article about games. Our choice is train games. Name of game is My Little Train";

    // Replace first pass
    $string = str_replace("train games", "<a href='http://www.myothersiteadrwesss.com'>train ga3mes</a>", $string);
    $string = str_replace("games", "<a href='http://www.mywebsite.com'>ga3mes</a>", $string);
    $string = str_replace("game", "<a href='http://www.my3thsiteadress.com'>ga3me</a>", $string);
    $string = str_replace("ga3me", "game", $string);
    echo $string;
?>
```

#### Output

```
Hello this article about <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com">games</a>. Our choice
is <a href="http://www.myothersiteadrwesss.com">train games</a>. Name of <a
href="http://www.my3thsiteadress.com">game</a> is My Little Train
```

#### Fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ny4-ium

#### Note

Just make sure, you replace something very big, complicated, and has all the words first. Next you go with the candidate words.

Using `str_replace`, this is the best way I can think of. Else, you need to use `regex` and give more complex searches and replaces.

Comment: This is wrong because my words must be <a href="blabla.com">games</a>, your way is compltelly replacing words. i just want to add links.

Comment: @user2006773 Now check the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would have all the words in keys in an array that points to the link like this:

```
$str = 'The original string that you want to replace games with!';
$arr = array('games' => 'http://website.com');
```

Then I would loop through that array and use `str_replace` to replace content in the string:

```
for($arr as $key => $val) {
   str_replace($key, $key . ' (' .  $val . ')', $str);
}
```

**This would produce:**

> The original string that you want to replace games
>   (http://website.com) with!